Why the Django static files are not loading after deployment?
I know this question has similar ones but nothing has been able make it for me. I've tried everything and every possible solution yet nothing helped including running all commands like python manage.py collectstatic.


settings.py:
# Media files (Uploaded files)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]

urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name="home"),
    path('signup/', signup_view, name='signup'),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', activate, name='activate'),
    path('login/', login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', logout, name='logout'),
    path('myprofile/', profile, name='profile'),
    path('myprofile/update', PROFILE_UPDATE, name='profileupdate'),
    path('reservation', reservation, name='reservation'),
    path('checkout/', checkout, name='checkout'),

    # Cards
    path('vegndaal/', vegndaal_page, name='vegndaal_page'),
    path('chicken/', chicken_page, name='chicken_page'),
    path('mutton/', mutton_page, name='mutton_page'),
    path('rice/', rice_page, name='rice_page'),
    path('tandoor/', tandoor_page, name='tandoor_page'),
    path('paratha/', paratha_page, name='paratha_page'),
    path('breakfast/', breakfast_page, name='breakfast_page'),
    path('fish/', fish_page, name='fish_page'),
    path('wrapsandsandwiches/', wrap_page, name='wrap_page'),
    path('burgersandwiches/', burger_page, name='burger_page'),
    path('combosandwiches/', combo_sandwiches, name='combo_sandwiches'),
    path('clubsandwiches/', club_sandwiches, name='club_sandwiches'),
    path('freshjuices/', juices_page, name='juices'),
    path('salads&softdrinks/', salad_page, name='salad'),
    path('milkshakes/', milk_shakes, name='milkshakes'),
    path('tea&coffee/', teancoffee, name='tea&coffee'),
    path('bbq/', bbq_page, name='bbq_page'),
    path('desserts/', desserts_page, name='desserts'),
    path('plateitems/', plate_items, name='plateitems'),
    path('grilled-tandoor/', grilled_tandoori_page, name='grilled_tandoori_page'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

The directory structure:
Restaurant/
│
├── app/
│   └── public/
│
├── Restaurant/
│
├── static/
│   ├── colors/
│   ├── css/
│   ├── images/
│   ├── js/
│   └── plugins/
│
├── staticfiles/
│   ├── admin/
│   ├── colors/
│   ├── css/
│   ├── images/
│   ├── js/
│   └── plugins/
│
├── templates/
│
└── tmp/


try ctrl + shift + r in webrowser.
